# Консольное меню с выбором строк

Tags: c#

**Нужна помощь в создании вот такого меню.(Навигация:UpArrow,DownArrow,Enter)**
[image: пример]

Comment: Полно уже готовых библиотек (первое что нашел, [Terminal.Gui](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs), которые позволят вам сделать все это, а так, самое примитивное, примерно [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60768075/6808809).

Comment: По ссылкам вверху решения вашего вопроса. Кстати, вы забыли в прошлом вашем вопросе принять ответ. Чтобы это сделать, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.